# Relation between OpenCL memory architecture and GPU's physical memory/caches (L1/L2...)?

Tags: memory, opencl, gpu

Is there any direct relation between the OpenCL memory architecture:

Local/Global/Constant/Private [memory](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/Memory-Spaces/image001.jpg)

And the physical GPU's memory and caches.
For example a GPU card that have 1GB memory/L1 cache/L2 cache. Are these related to local/global.. memory?

Or are Local/Constant/Private memory allocated from Global memory?
-Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCL doesn't really discuss caching of memory.  Most modern graphics cards do have some sort of caching protocols for global memory, but these are not guaranteed in older cards.  However here is an overview of the different memories.

**Private Memory** - This memory is kept as registers per work-item.  GPUs have very large register files per compute unit.  However this memory can spill into local memory if needed.  Private memory is allocated by default when you create variables.

**Local Memory** - Memory local to and shared by the workgroup.  This memory system typically is on the compute unit itself and cannot be read or written to by other workgroups.  This memory has typically very low latency on GPU architectures (on CPU architectures, this memory is simply part of your system memory).  This memory is typically used as a manual cache for global memory.  Local memory is specified by the `__local` attribute.

**Constant Memory** - Part of the global memory, but read only and can therefore be aggressively cached.  `__constant` is used to define this type of memory.

**Global Memory** - This is the main memory of the GPU.  `__global` is used to place memory into the global memory space.

Comment: I appreciate it. Could you also tell if I can allocate a Private/Local Memory of 50% the size of Global Memory? ... in modern GPUs

Comment: @Maiss: for modern gpus local memory per compute unit is somewhere between 16kB and 64kB (and doesn't spill to global memory afaik). So no you can't

Comment: I've read various sources saying that private memory can be off-chip DRAM, which would make it the slowest, but that recent GPUs cache this memory into registers/L1, the highest up in the mem hierarchy. Could somebody confirm this? And whether there's a way to determine the nature of your private mem? Seems like it could be the slowest (off-chip) or the fastest possible (registers).

Comment: @YoungMoney I've never heard of private memory for GPUs being on off-chip DRAM.  This seems like it would be extremely counter-intuitive if there was a cache to not use it.  All modern GPUs have L1/L2 caches for private memory.  The only way that private memory can be in the off-chip DRAM would be though a register spill, which will only happen if you force it (as the GPU will instead just allocate fewer work-groups to the compute unit to avoid spilling).

Comment: What is LDS that is mentioned in some manuals of AMD gpus' ? Maybe __local ?